# how to search permutated word or number in database

Tags: permutation

I have create a search form that can search the data from my database and show the result.
Now I have try to create a search form that can search the permutated words.

Example,
I have a textfield in the form for keyin the keyword to search. What to do if I want to search "tea" but the results returned from the database not only "tea" but also "tae", "eat", "ate", "eta", and "aet".

I know how to generate the list of permutated word of tea but I don't know how to search tea but the script will auto search the permutated words also.

Can I use wildcard for this? 
I have think that generate the permutated words first and then search with the permutated words that list out. But it is not work.

Any idea or help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generate all permutation resutls and send list to database and query using IN clause for each list item.

Comment: how to send list to database??You mean that first i need to generate all permutation results and second send list to database and third query with IN clause?